# after Checkbox check sum will be display at label

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function recalculate() {
            var sum = 0;
            $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
                sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
            });
            $("#tot").html(sum);
        }
        $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
            recalculate();
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" Height="500px" Width="500px" ActiveTabIndex="0">
            <asp:TabPanel ID="tbpnl1" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>Product</HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Product</b>
                            </td>
                            <td><b>Price</b>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Microsoft Sharepoint</td>
                            <td>300</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="300">
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Visual Studio</td>
                            <td>500</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="500">
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Cando UI</td>
                            <td>600</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="600">
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Quick heal</td>
                            <td>400</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="400">
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Test</td>
                            <td>100</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="100">
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><b>Total</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="tot" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TabPanel>
            <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>User Details</HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                        <table align="center" border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2"></td>
                                <td>    <b>User Details</b>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2">UserName:</td>
                                <td>    <b>Suresh Dasari</b>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2">FirstName:</td>
                                <td>    <b>Suresh</b>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2">LastName:</td>
                                <td>    <b>Dasari</b>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2">Email:</td>
                                <td>    <b>sureshbabudasari@gmail.com</b>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2">Phone No:</td>
                                <td>    <b>1234567890</b>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2">Location:</td>
                                <td align="left">   <b>Hyderabad</b>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TabPanel>
        </asp:TabContainer>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
            sum += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $("#tot").html(sum);
    });
});
```

Comment: i want sum after checkbox check.........but it nt displaying anything...i think script not working